# Can't upgrade from 18.04 server to 20.04

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, upgrade, do-release-upgrade

After running:

```shell
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

I get the following error:

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release In /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades Prompt is set to never so upgrading is not possible.
```

But I want to upgrade, so how can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to check your `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` file. You'll find at the bottom the following line:

```
Prompt=never
```

Change this to:

```
Prompt=normal
```

Once this is done, you'll be able to upgrade to the latest LTS

Comment: 18.04 server like the title saids. Do i really need to install a GUI to make this work?

Comment: Updated. I should read more carefully sometimes ...

Comment: Use `Prompt=lts` for LTS !